# Вызов метода в отдельном потоке, python-telegram-bot API.

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, multiprocessing

Пилится бот для Telegram. 
Использую python3 и python-telegram-bot 
Надо связать команду `/sign_up` и метод `sign_up()` так, что бы метод запускался в отдельном потоке. Изначально код был такой:

```
sign_up_handler = CommandHandler('sign_up', self.sign_up)
self.dispatcher.add_handler(sign_up_handler)
```

Потом решил прилепить потоки:

```
from threading import Thread
sign_up_handler = CommandHandler('sign_up', Thread(target=self.sign_up).start)
```

Однако этот код не работает, потому что библиотека передает в связанный метод два аргумента: `bot` и `updater`.

```
TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CommandHandler('sign_up', lambda *a, **kw: Thread(target=self.sign_up, args=a, kwargs=kw).start())
```